# SQLite Update Statement error

Tags: android, sqlite, content-values

for my update i want to search corrent pos using `inspectionid`, `activityid`, `subactivityid` but when calling update state ment im getting this error.can some one help.

```
public int updateSubActivityActivityComment(String comment, int rating, int subActivityId, int activityId, int inspectionId){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(KEY_RATING, rating);
    contentValues.put(KEY_COMMENT, comment);

    return db.updateWithOnConflict(TABLE_INSPECTION, contentValues,KEY_SUB_ACTIVITY_ID+ " = ? "+subActivityId+" AND "+KEY_INSPECTION_ID + " = ? "+inspectionId +" AND "+KEY_ACTIVITY_ID +" = ? "+activityId,new String[]{String.valueOf(subActivityId)} ,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
}
```

Log Cat-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many bind arguments.  3 arguments were provided but the statement needs 2 arguments.
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:68)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1574)
                                                     at com.theavo.ck_app.DatabaseHelper.updateSubActivityActivityComment(DatabaseHelper.java:264)
                                                     at com.theavo.ck_app.FragmentSubInspectionComment.onClick(FragmentSubInspectionComment.java:470)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: There is three `?, ?, ?` question mark but only 2 values are passed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass three values here

```
String[] whereArgs =  new String[]{String.valueOf(subActivityId),String.valueOf(inspectionId),String.valueOf(activityId)};

db.updateWithOnConflict(TABLE_INSPECTION, contentValues,KEY_SUB_ACTIVITY_ID+ " = ? "+" AND "+KEY_INSPECTION_ID + " = ? "+" AND "+KEY_ACTIVITY_ID +" = ? ",whereArgs ,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `updateWithOnConflict` method as by passing 4th parameter as `null` and remove `?` from 3rd parameter:

```
db.updateWithOnConflict(TABLE_INSPECTION,contentValues,
          KEY_SUB_ACTIVITY_ID+ " = "
          +subActivityId+" AND "+KEY_INSPECTION_ID + " = "
          +inspectionId +" AND "+KEY_ACTIVITY_ID +" = "
          +activityId,null ,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

because already passing values with column names in 3rd parameter then no need to pass it again.